# Copy newest or latest files using .bat command

Tags: batch-file, copy

I have to copy the latest or newest files from a server to another server.

I have a code like this

```
@echo off
set source="\\tsclient\F\Project Documentation"
set target="C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\DS\datafiles"

FOR /F "delims=" %%I IN ('DIR %source%\*.xml /A:-D /O:-D /B') DO COPY %source%\"%%I" %target% & echo %%I & GOTO :END
:END
TIMEOUT 4
```

The issue is, this will only copy 1 file, there are two new files. How to copy the second one?

Comment: How do you know which files are considered "newest?" From the original question, it makes sense that it would only copy 1 file, as only 1 file can truly be the newest. Can you provide an example of the folder structure and sample files and describe the behavior you expect please?

Comment: Newest is based on the modified date of the file.

Comment: If you're going based on the modified date, how can you have 2 "newest?" One file will nearly always be SLIGHTLY newer than another… Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Yes you are correct. Say the files were modified y'day, so i need both the files that were modified yday? How can i do that?

Comment: Can you please post an example of the potential files in a folder, their date modified, and the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with delayed expansion and a loop variable like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "source=\\tsclient\F\Project Documentation"
set "target=C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\DS\datafiles"

set loop=1
FOR /F "delims=" %%I IN ('DIR "%source%\*.xml" /A:-D /O:-D /B') DO (
    COPY "%source%\%%~nxI" "%target%"
    echo %source%\%%~nxI
    if !loop! equ 2 GOTO END
    set /a loop+=1
)
:END
TIMEOUT 4
```

It'll always copy 2 files, though.  If you have only one new file, you'll still copy two.

Comment: This is not working. No files are copied and throwing error that the network path is not found.

Comment: The error says destination path C:\Users\xyz\Desktop\DS\datafiles not valid. It is working though with my earlier code.

Comment: Did you leave `"%target%"` quoted?  Try putting `@echo on` just before the `for /f` loop and see what the last command attempted is before the failure.

Comment: From ECHO on what i understand is the issue with the target C:\Users\egopaa02\Desktop\DS\nfc_data_files\file.xml is invalid. Something to do with this  "%source%\%%~fI" "%target%". Its taking the xml file also as target.

Comment: I'm so sorry.  That was a silly error on my part.  Try the new edit.